# How to get rid of 'People who change these files...' changelist in IntelliJ Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm on **IntelliJ 2019.2.4 (Ultimate)** I'm not sure of the version I upgraded from, but it was from 2018 for sure. I noticed this annoying changelist below my default changelist in a very click-baity way, and I can't find a setting to get rid of it. Trying to delete it prompts me to delete the actual file in that changelist, which I don't want to do. It's nothing I've set up, and seems to be something IntelliJ is doing automatically.

[image]

(For posterity/if the image dies, my screenshot shows my changelist with some files I changed in default, and then a second, unwanted changelist below that says 'People who change the files in the active changelist also change:

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The node you see is not actually a changelist, and there are no changed files inside it. It lists files that, based on your project git history, are usually changed in the same commits as the files in the active changelist, and appear related to the changes you applied.

The purpose of this node is to suggest some files you might want to change and commit in addition to already modified files, so there is no need to amend or create a new commit with these changes later if the files do need to be modified as well.

If you don't want to see it, just disable the **Show files related to the active changelist** option under the Eye in the Local Changes toolbar. Disabling the *ChangeReminder* plugin would also work, but is unnecessary.
[image]

Comment: Probably the worst 'feature' I've ever seen.

Comment: It would be great to provide different message for this node as it makes a lot of confusion

Comment: Clearly a feature that did not get tested with real developers..